# Mongo DB - Making an aggregation with the values of an array inside a document

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

So i have the folowing cenario:
A first colection (users) with all my users and their object ids:

```
{
  "_id"  : ObjectId("...."),
  "name" : "Avg Joe"
}
```

And i have another colection (managers) where my Users contain another users, that can be found by its c_id on users colection :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
  "m_id" : "ObjectIdFromTheUsersColection",
  "clients" : [
     {
       "c_id" : "ObjectIdFromTheUsersColection",
       "name" : "Avg Client"
     },
     {
       "c_id" : "ObjectIdFromTheUsersColection",
       "name" : "Avg Client II"
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able of selecting an user from the second colection (managers) and retrieve it´s clients from the frist colection (users).

Comment: Can you add the expected output you want? I've understood you want [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xcYWQ5S2EVN) but I'm not sure. By the way, use `$lookup` is that you need. With an output example I can reproduce the query you need.

Comment: Thanks J.F. my development team instead opted for another aproach on the problem. Instead of indirect relation we inserted directly on the documents we needed